# SSL certificate does not appear automatically

Tags: ssl

I have bought SSL certificate for my domain and have installed successfully. But the problem is when I type my domain https:// does not appear automatically and when I Type manually https:// it is appeared without any problem. What should I do that when the users type my domain it appears with https:// automatically?

Thanks

Comment: You will need to redirect user that connects from port 80 (http) and redirect them to 443 (https) in the server config

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Good luck :)